# Capacitor GoogleMaps Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to test in IOS my ionic app, using the capacitor maps to show a map in the app, in the browser it works correctly, but in native iOS devices or simulator, the maps is show this error:

```
CapacitorGoogleMaps/Map.swift:125: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

CapacitorGoogleMaps/Map.swift:125: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

I try passing the styles to the map directly from ts and from css, but still dont work.

My code:

HTML & CSS

```
<capacitor-google-map #map [style.hidden]="!isMapLoading"></capacitor-google-map>

capacitor-google-map {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

TS

````
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.createMap();
  }

  async createMap() {
    const {
      coords: { latitude, longitude }
    } = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();

    const mapOptions: CreateMapArgs = {
      id: 'my-cool-map',
      element: this.mapElementRef.nativeElement,
      apiKey: MAP_API_KEY,
      config: { ...MAP_INITIAL_CONFIG, center: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude} }
    };```
````